# Disable mute tab animation

Tags: firefox, about-config

Starting with Firefox 52.

If you are on YouTube or similar, and hit play, the mute tab button comes up immediately. However if you then hit pause, it is about a 5 second delay now before the mute tab button disappears. Can this be fixed via about:config or similar?

I would like to restore the previous state, which is the mute tab button responds immediately to both play and pause. Failing that I would like to at least reduce the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the browser console:

```js
Services.prefs.setIntPref('browser.tabs.delayHidingAudioPlayingIconMS', 0);
```

http://reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/5z4wr8/disable_mute_tab_animation/devb4be